# How do I change the color of the titlebar close button in KDE Plasma 5.21?

Tags: kde, window, plasma, appearance

I don't see an option for this in the `System Settings` option. Is it possible to do this one?

Comment: That's a Kwin's theme dependent - most themes don't allow to customize window controls colors.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Is there a configuration file though, where such a thing could be modified?

Comment: None that I'm aware of.